# REST Serialization escapes URLs

Tags: 8

Since updating to 8.3 we've noticed that some URL's in our REST responses are being escaped (this may have been happening before but I don't think so as it is now causing issues with the Android parser).

The URL's are escaped like this;

```
{"_links":
    {"self":
        {"href":"http:\/\/example.com\/api\/resource\/80?_format=hal_json"}
```

Those w's (//) and v's (/) are killing things and I'd like to remove this escaping.

BTW, this API is password protected and used by a controlled app only. While removing this escaping may introduce issues with public API's and security/stabiliy, we don't need this level of control.

Can I just override the `Serialize` class and use that?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I can't see how this could have been different prior to 8.3 - PHP's `json_encode` seems to have been escaping `/` by default forever, and neither Drupal nor Symfony seem to have overridden that in the past.

The service ID and class you would need to override is `serializer.encoder.json` (`Drupal\serialization\Encoder\JsonEncoder`), adding a `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` to the options bitmask in the constructor. (Confusingly, there's a separate service named `serialization.json`, which isn't the one that's used here.)

However, note that `\/` is a valid escape sequence in JSON (if not strictly required), and a JSON parser [must interpret this as a literal forward slash character](http://www.json.org/) to be working correctly. There should be no backslashed URLs in the parsed values. Is it possible that your client's parser library has a bug?